# how to add comma in textfield in html web page

Tags: javascript, input, html

I have a web page in which I input data into an `<input />`, like 1000 so I want it to look like 1,000 but it does not change the ID value it just show for only becuase I am using same the ID in other calculation so if 1,000 then it will show NaN... how can I avoid this?

```
<input type="text" id="test" onBlur="addCommas()">
<script>
    function addCommas(nStr){
        var offset = nStr.length % 3;
        if (offset == 0)
            return nStr.substring(0, offset) + nStr.substring(offset).replace(/([0-9]{3})(?=[0-9]+)/g, "$1,");
        else
            return nStr.substring(0, offset) + nStr.substring(offset).replace(/([0-9]{3})/g,    ",$1");
    }
    alert(addCommas("1234567"));
</script>
```

I have got this code from a forum... does anyone have an idea how to make this function simple so that it just shows in input box but when I get the ID value it shows 1000?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript might help you

Comment: @Pete thanks for support can you please tell me how to use this method in mine id and how will it change display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test your value with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric/174921#174921) :

```
function isNumber(n) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

it will prevent your NAN's.

And use @Pete's [link to know how to print a number with commas as thousands separators in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript)

EDIT About your comment : 
Then you can use a `<input type="hidden" id="testValue" />` and store the real value in it.

So your code will look like :

```
<input type="text" id="test" onBlur="addCommas(this)">
<input type="hidden" id="testRealValue">
<script>
    function isNumber(n) {
        return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
    }
    function addCommas(input){
        nStr = input.value;
        if(!isNumber(nStr))return;
        document.getElementById("testRealValue").value = nStr;
        var offset = nStr.length % 3;
        if (offset == 0)
            input.value = nStr.substring(0, offset) + nStr.substring(offset).replace(/([0-9]{3})(?=[0-9]+)/g, "$1,");
        else
            input.value = nStr.substring(0, offset) + nStr.substring(offset).replace(/([0-9]{3})/g,    ",$1");
    }
</script>
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FhZ6y/)

Comment: i am not asking about NAN i am asking to display commma in out put only

Comment: can you please edit in jsfiddle i am not getting this

Comment: it will also change id value or it just display like this

Comment: As you cannot store and display 2 differents values in an input, It will display the value as "1,000" and store the real value in the hidden input with id = "testRealValue", check out the jsfiddle, i edited my post.

Comment: but it is not working in my html file it is working in jsfiddle